# Adding a column qualifier to many LINQ to SQL constructs at once

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a dbml to which I have added more then 15 tables from an SQL Server 2008 DB.  I then have about 50 LINQ to SQL queries, some quite complex, running against one or more of these tables.

And now the spec has changed, as they tend to do, and there is a version column added to all of these tables, and all the queries need to operate on data from a specific version.

so for example

```
dim q = from a in dbc.T1, b in dbc.T2
        where a.c1=b.c2 And
        a.c2 > param1
```

needs to become

```
dim q = from a in dbc.T1, b in dbc.T2
        where a.c1=b.c2 And
        a.c2 > param1 And
        a.version = version_param And 
        b.version = version_param
```

As I said, the LINQ statements are much more complex, and usually involve several tables in each.

Any clever ideas on how I can implement this without editing each query and inserting an

```
        a.version = version_param
```

qualifier for each table involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a proxy for your context

```
class ContextProxy
{
   MyDbContext _dbc;
   int _t1version = ...;
   ... etc

   public ContextProxy(MyDbContext dbc){ _dbc = dbc; }

   public IQueryable<T1Type> T1
   {
      get{ return _dbc.T1.Where( t => t.version == _t1version );
   }

   ... etc
}
```

and then use that in place of the *dbc* context in your existing queries.

Comment: I does not answer the question how to modify existing queries, but it does suggest what would be the best practice in such situation, thus +1.

Comment: Actually the question was how to implement the requirement without editing each query. And thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: This answers the question beautifully, and i'm done implementing it already! very nice and definitely +1